# MySql SELECT with if statement and LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, sql-like

I am working on an advertisement site.

I have one table with a column for each day. I need to check in the table which ads is saved as default to update only those ads.

I have tried this, but it not working.

```
SELECT Monday if (Monday LIKE '%default%'),
Tuesday if (Tuesday LIKE '%default%')
FROM `Ad_Relationshp`
```

MySql gives me this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (Monday LIKE '%default%') FROM `Ad_Relationshp` LIMIT 0,' at line 1. I have tried changing the syntax to everything I can think off, but I still get the same error.

Comment: What`s the expected result?

Comment: To show only the columns which has 'default' in them

Comment: If you can provide table structure and expected result it would be great

Comment: Can you share your table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are using the if conditional branching which is only possible in procedures and triggers,use the if function.

```
SELECT if (`Monday` LIKE '%default%',`Monday`,''),
if (`Tuesday` LIKE '%default%',`Tuesday`,'')
FROM `Ad_Relationshp`


SELECT `Monday`,`Tuesday`
FROM `Ad_Relationshp`
WHERE `Monday` LIKE '%default%'
OR `Tuesday` LIKE '%default%'
```

Comment: Hi Mihai. Thanks. I am almost there. The Field contains a pathway to an image saved in a directory on the server. Your SELECT works and gives me a result, but instead of showing me the pathway, it shows 'Monday'

Comment: @Anoniem I edited it assuming path is the column,replace path with your column name where the path is stored

Comment: If it doesn't contain the 'default' it shows the column name with no path. Which is fine. Is there a way to exclude the column from the result if 'default' is not in the column content?